# Hibernate, Spring and SLF4J Binding

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven-2, slf4j

I'm trying to setup a webapp with maven2 managed dependcies. Here my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mtx-production</groupId>
    <artifactId>mtx-production</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jboss-releases</id>
          <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Correct me if I got something wrong but this should work?! I only getting in my eclipse this exception

```
    13.06.2010 16:48:15 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
    INFO: Bean 'dataSource' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    13.06.2010 16:48:15 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
    INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@366573: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,myTxManager,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
    13.06.2010 16:48:15 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    SCHWERWIEGEND: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:408)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3830)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4337)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:266)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
```

What is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Include the slf4j-api in your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Exclude the commons-logging dependency for minimum one of your declared spring dependencies and provide the slf4j facade for commons-logging:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Include the log4j dependency for your logging together with the slf4j facade:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.14</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

A great blog post for further reading about logging with SLF4J and Spring can be found in the SpringSource Team blog under http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/.

Comment: Following this advices worked out - now I'm getting another exception. Well its a step forward.

Comment: Is it still any logging related exception?

Comment: No, now it is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter` importing javassist dependcy doesn't works... Think I just let this world burn...

Comment: just exclude "commons-logging" from every spring component! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

This should indeed work, the **slf4j-log4j12** binding contains `org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder`.

1. Try to clean and redeploy your application, maybe something went wrong during deployment.
2. Double check that the downloaded **slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar** is not corrupted (try to open it).
3. Maybe even delete it and let maven re-download it.

Some unrelated remarks:

- Instead of repeating frameworks version in dependencies, you should use a property. For example:

  ```
  ...
  <properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    ...
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ```
- `hibernate-core` is a transitive dependency of `hibernate-annotations`, you don't need to declare it (if you want to use JPA, you should actually depend on `hibernate-entitymanager`).

Comment: 1. done several times - no success here
2. the file is ok - I can open it in eclipse or per fs
3. tried this too - no success too.

I tried instead of `slf4j-log4j12`other bindings with no effect. I only get this exception

Answer (score 1):

You are missing

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: That's a transitive dependency of Hibernate, the OP has this dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate depends on slf4j-api, so declaring it yourself shouldn't make any difference. Apart from that, I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate depends on slf4j-api, so you need to add missing dependency in you pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0-beta4</version>
</dependency>
```