# spring, hibernate, log4j for centralized error catching

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, log4j, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0, Spring, Hibernate and I need to implement Log4J for centralized error catching. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log4j has absolutely nothing to do with spring, jsf or hibernate.

- place `log4j.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib`
- get a sampel `log4j.properties` and place in on the root of your classpath
- use `private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CurrentClass.class);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want **centralized** logging and since you are using Spring and Hibernate, things are a bit more complicated than just providing a `log4j.properties` because Hibernate uses SLF4J as logging facade while Spring uses Jakarta Commons Logging (JCL) as logging facade and [they seem to conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032654/hibernate-spring-and-slf4j-binding).

My recommendation would be to use SLF4J and for that, you'll need to:

- provide `slf4j-api.jar` (you should actually get this one with Hibernate)
- remove `commons-logging.jar` that comes from Spring
- provide `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` to bridge JCL calls to SLF4J
- provide the SLF4J binding for Log4J (`slf4j-log4j12.jar`) to bridge SLF4J calls to Log4J
- provide `log4j.jar`

#### See also

- [Hibernate, Spring and SLF4J Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032654/hibernate-spring-and-slf4j-binding)
- [Logging Dependencies in Spring](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/)