# Hibernate symbols @id @column are not recognized

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven-2

In my User class, I'm trying to add the symbols @id and @column.

I'm getting a compile error:

cannot find symbol class id/column.

I'm using IDEA.

**In the docs, I don't see any reference for @Id and @Column: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/**

I have this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.1rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1beta4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1beta4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Hard to tell just from this: Perhaps show the class that doesn't compile.  BTW you have hibernate-annotations listed twice in your dependencies.  And why are you using a two-year old beta version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the JPA 1.0 implementation, you need the following dependencies:

```
<properties>
  <org.hibernate.version>3.4.0.GA</org.hibernate.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, we use log4j as backend -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you want to use the JPA 2.0 implementation, simply replace the `org.hibernate.version` by:

```
<properties>
  <org.hibernate.version>3.5.3-Final</org.hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

In both cases, the above Hibernate dependency will give you **everything** you need transitively.

---

As you may have noticed, Hibernate uses SLF4J while Spring uses Jakarta Commons Logging. I suggest to configure Spring to use SLF4J as well as explained in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032654/hibernate-spring-and-slf4j-binding).

#### See also

- [Logging Dependencies in Spring](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/)
- [Why is commons-logging believed to be unpopular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222895/why-is-commons-logging-believed-to-be-unpopular/3223701#3223701)

Comment: @Blankman: JPA is a standard that Hibernate implements (the JPA implementation is provided by *Hibernate Entity Manager* which depends on *Hibernate Annotations*). I would recommend using JPA over the Hibernate specific annotations.

Answer (score 2):

Java is case sensitive. It's `@Id` and `@Column`. Also, those are JPA annotations, i.e. they're not part of Hibernate but of Java EE (in the `javax.persistence` package). The corresponding Hibernate annotations are `@PrimaryKey` and `@Column` from the `org.hibernate.mapping` package.

Comment: i can't get org.hibernate.annotations.Id to work...hmmm...I have:    <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1beta4</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @Blankman: I was mistaken about the location of those annotations (@Id is from JPA, not Hibernate). I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is java's persistence annotation
You can either add dependency of

javax.persistence:persistence-api

Although adding dependency to hibernate entity manager will resolve you transitively, I would still recommend to add dependencies that you have really used in your artifact.